# Why is my overloaded function call ambiguous?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm reading the book Essential C++ and trying out some of the examples in it. The following code from Chapter 3 was supposed to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <typename IteratorType, typename elemType>
IteratorType find(IteratorType first, IteratorType last, const elemType &value)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first)
        if (value == *first)
            return first;
    return last;
};

int main()
{
    int asize = 8;
    int ia[asize] = {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21};
    
    int *pia = find(ia, ia + asize, 1024);
    if (pia != ia + asize)
        cout<<"found in array"<<endl;
    else
    {
        cout<<"not found in array"<<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

However, it's showing the error

> call of overloaded ‘find(int [asize], int*, int)’ is ambiguous

Then I replaced

```
int *pia = find(ia, ia + asize, 1024);
```

with

```
int *pia = find(&ia[0], ia + asize, 1024);
```

Now it's showing the error

> call of overloaded ‘find(int*, int*, int)’ is ambiguous

I'm working with Ubuntu 18.04 and G++ 7.5.0.

I would appreciate it if anyone can let me know what the correct implementation should be.

Comment: Probably clashing with `std::find` since you used `import namespace std;`

Comment: That solves the problem! Thank you so much!